# StaticInjectorError/NullInjectorError - With AOT

Tags: typescript, angular5, ngrx-effects

I have a service that I need to inject into an ngrx effects module. I also need this service injected into the root of my application. I added the service to the application's providers list. This all compiles and runs just fine, until I run AOT compilation.

In my `ItemsEffects` class (one of my effects classes), I get this

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[AppMonitoringService]:
  StaticInjectorError[AppMonitoringService]:
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AppMonitoringService!
```

This effects class is imported in my effects module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EffectsModule.forRoot([
      // ...effects classes
    ])
})
export class MyEffectsModule { }
```

The effects module is imported into one other module, which is imported into my root application module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(/* reducers included here */),
    MyEffectsModule,
  ],
});
export class MyStoreModule{ }
```

The module above is imported into my root module as mentioned above:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyStoremodule
  ],
});
export class AppModule { }
```

And of course the class in question simply tries to inject the service:

```
@Injectable() 
export class ItemsEffects{
  constructor (private appMonSvc: AppMonitoringService) {
  }
}
```

...which leads to the error mentioned at the beginning:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[AppMonitoringService]:
  StaticInjectorError[AppMonitoringService]:
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AppMonitoringService!
```

I have tried importing the service into every conceivable spot. I've tried using the `{provider: AppMonitoringService}` syntaxes, I've attempted removing the provider from the root app module, I've even tried writing my own forRoot syntax to import it and none of it works.

The strangest thing is that several of my effects are importing services from across the app. The way this one is defined is identical, and it has no dependencies. I am curious if anyone has any idea what might be going on, and how I might be able to solve this? I'm 99% certain I've read every issue on SO relating to this issue as well as github and angular 2 support. Now need to turn to the community directly.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I'm on angular 5.0.1 and Typescript 2.4.2

Comment: In what module are you adding AppMonitoringService to the list of providers? (providers: [AppMonitoringService]) also, does the AppMonitoringService have the @Injectable decorator?

Comment: Yes, it has the @Injectable decorator. I am adding the monitoring service provider to to the root AppModule, which should make it globally available. The only thing I can think of is that the effects module tries to instantiate its classes before the root module has access to its providers...? I mean, effects are injectables as well so if it does it from the bottom up this would make sense. But it would also stand to reason that adding the monitoring service to the effects module would solve the problem, which it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried this: EffectsModule.forFeature instead of EffectsModule.forRoot in MyEffectsModule?

Comment: @Juan No, but isn't that for lazy loading? I need the service available in the root. I can try it but don't have much hope on that front.

Comment: I experience something similar, by similar i mean the injection error only appearing with aot build - my case is not related to ngrx i believe. I build a providers array variable and dont ask me why (?!?!) but I could fix my problem by initializing the array with the problematic service instead of pushing it to the array. Maybe you are doing something similar? Have you find a solution?

Comment: I could also improve my fix by providing the service with 'useFactory', let me know if you need a snippet of how to do it.